# Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'emailReducer.emails.0'

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I'm getting this error message about mutating state, but the purpose of Redux Toolkit is mutating state, so I'm confused...

The error is coming from `addNewEmail`,  where I'm adding new emails to the array calling `prevEmails` using `useSelector` and the second parameter is a regular string.

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { AppThunk } from "./store";

const initialState = {
   emails: [],
};

export const emailSlice = createSlice({
   name: "email",
   initialState,
   reducers: {
      setEmails: (state, action: any) => {
         state.emails = action.payload;
      },
   },
});

export const { setEmails } = emailSlice.actions;

export const addNewEmail = (prevEmails: any, email: string): AppThunk => (
   dispatch
) => {
   const allEmails = prevEmails.push(email);
   dispatch(setEmails(allEmails));
};

export default emailSlice.reducer;

export const selectEmails = (state: any) => state.emailReducer.emails;
```

Answer (score 14):

I was also getting the same error, this is not how you disptach the
action. All you have to pass this middlewares in your store.

```
const store = configureStore({
          reducer,
          middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
               immutableCheck: false,
               serializableCheck: false,
          })
})
```

Comment: This can help people who are upgrading their existing redux app to redux-toolkit.

Comment: Like me! I spent ages trying to work out why i was getting immutable error, thanks immutableCheck: false fixed for me.

Comment: Life saver. This is exactly what the project needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

As @asaf-aviv said, the real problem is that you're attempting to mutate what is actually `state.emails`, outside of a reducer:

```js
   const allEmails = prevEmails.push(email);
   dispatch(setEmails(allEmails));
```

The second problem is conceptual.  You should [model actions as "events", not "setters"](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#model-actions-as-events-not-setters), and [put as much logic as possible into reducers](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#put-as-much-logic-as-possible-in-reducers).  If you follow those guidelines, this problem won't occur in the first place.

Also, this doesn't even need to be a thunk - just dispatch an action that contains the new email object.

The *right* way to handle this is:

```js
export const emailSlice = createSlice({
   name: "email",
   initialState,
   reducers: {
      emailAdded: (state, action: PayloadAction<Email>) => {
         state.emails.push(action.payload)
      },
   },
});

export const { emailAdded } = emailSlice.actions;


// later
dispatch(emailAdded(newEmail));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating the state before dispatching the action, you can do mutations inside the reducer but not outside of it.

You can change `prevEmails.push(email)` to `prevEmails.concat(email)` which will return a new array which you can then send as a payload.